# gdaldem exact color matching fails

Tags: colormap, gdaldem

I'm using gdaldem color-relief to read a Uint32 raster and write an RGB tif. The input color_text_file has one line:

`102216130    23:105:102`

My input file is a single (large) pixel of value 102216130, matching the one line in the color text file.

If I run gdaldem with the `-exact_color_entry` flag, the output is a pixel with RGB 0 0 0. If I run it without the flag, the output is correct, a pixel with 23 105 102.

Why is this? It certainly doesn't matter for this raster (`-exact_color_entry` appears to be unnecessary), but for rasters with more lookup values in the color text file (700, in one case), the general case (i.e. not using `-exact_color_entry`) is important, as output colors do not exactly match my input.

The [help page for gdaldem](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html) states that `-exact_color_entry`:

> use strict matching when searching in the color configuration file. If none matching color entry is found, the "0,0,0,0" RGBA quadruplet will be used

Can I edit this color configuration file? The colors that are being approximated seem normal (R 21, G 191, B 217 for example) but the exact values are not being written to tiff.

Alternatively, is there a better tool than gdaldem for essentially reclassifying one raster to three bands?

Comment: It feels like value 102216130 is changing a bit for some reason in the process. I can't imagine why and how but perhaps gdaldem is not heavily tested with single pixel images.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what the deal is either. The strange thing is that this happens for large pixel images as well. Setting `-exact_color_entry` leads to an all black output image when the input is a 500 px by 500 px raster.

Comment: I suggest to write to gdal-dev mailing list and attach 1x1 or 500x500 image as an attachment.